# Running cordova app in Xcode 5 breaks plugins

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

If I create a new cordova project, add the ios patform, add the org.apache.cordova.device plugin, then "cordova build ios" everything is fine.

If then, I open the project in xcode and run on the simulator.  Then "cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera".  Every "cordova build ios" fails with:

```
william-macbook-pro:pluginapp william$ cordova build ios
Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "ios"
Preparing ios project
Compiling app on platform "ios" via command "/Users/william/working/pluginapp/platforms/ios/cordova/build" 

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: An error occurred while building the ios project.2014-01-16 14:29:23.881 xcodebuild[1838:1007] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID 37B30044-3B14-46BA-ABAA-F01000C27B63 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/XCode4_beginning_of_line.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2014-01-16 14:29:24.263 xcodebuild[1838:4207]  DeveloperPortal: Using pre-existing current store at URL (file:///Users/william/Library/Developer/Xcode/DeveloperPortal%205.0.2.db).
2014-01-16 14:29:24.463 xcodebuild[1850:1007] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID 37B30044-3B14-46BA-ABAA-F01000C27B63 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/XCode4_beginning_of_line.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2014-01-16 14:29:24.871 xcodebuild[1850:4703]  DeveloperPortal: Using pre-existing current store at URL (file:///Users/william/Library/Developer/Xcode/DeveloperPortal%205.0.2.db).
2014-01-16 14:29:25.126 xcodebuild[1860:1007] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID 37B30044-3B14-46BA-ABAA-F01000C27B63 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/XCode4_beginning_of_line.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2014-01-16 14:29:25.584 xcodebuild[1860:4107]  DeveloperPortal: Using pre-existing current store at URL (file:///Users/william/Library/Developer/Xcode/DeveloperPortal%205.0.2.db).
2014-01-16 14:29:28.476 xcodebuild[1860:2407]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-3575/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/SpecificationTypes/XCGccMakefileDependencies.m:78
Details:  Failed to load dependencies output contents from ``/Users/william/working/pluginapp/platforms/ios/build/HelloCordova.build/Debug-iphoneos/HelloCordova.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVCamera.d''. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “CDVCamera.d” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo=0x7fd19428f110 {NSFilePath=/Users/william/working/pluginapp/platforms/ios/build/HelloCordova.build/Debug-iphoneos/HelloCordova.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVCamera.d, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd1948242a0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}. User info: {
    NSFilePath = "/Users/william/working/pluginapp/platforms/ios/build/HelloCordova.build/Debug-iphoneos/HelloCordova.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVCamera.d";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. No such file or directory\"";
}.
Function: void XCGccMakefileDependenciesParsePathsFromRuleFile(NSString *__strong, F) [F = <lambda at /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-3575/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/SpecificationTypes/XCGccMakefileDependencies.m:168:73>]
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fd19428f150>{name = (null), num = 7}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2014-01-16 14:29:28.498 xcodebuild[1860:3d23]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-3575/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/SpecificationTypes/XCGccMakefileDependencies.m:78
Details:  Failed to load dependencies output contents from ``/Users/william/working/pluginapp/platforms/ios/build/HelloCordova.build/Debug-iphoneos/HelloCordova.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVJpegHeaderWriter.d''. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “CDVJpegHeaderWriter.d” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo=0x7fd194685510 {NSFilePath=/Users/william/working/pluginapp/platforms/ios/build/HelloCordova.build/Debug-iphoneos/HelloCordova.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVJpegHeaderWriter.d, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd1946af240 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}. User info: {
    NSFilePath = "/Users/william/working/pluginapp/platforms/ios/build/HelloCordova.build/Debug-iphoneos/HelloCordova.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVJpegHeaderWriter.d";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. No such file or directory\"";
}.
Function: void XCGccMakefileDependenciesParsePathsFromRuleFile(NSString *__strong, F) [F = <lambda at /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-3575/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/SpecificationTypes/XCGccMakefileDependencies.m:168:73>]
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fd1946b0d60>{name = (null), num = 8}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC build/HelloCordova.build/Debug-iphoneos/HelloCordova.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVCamera.o HelloCordova/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.camera/CDVCamera.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC build/HelloCordova.build/Debug-iphoneos/HelloCordova.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVJpegHeaderWriter.o HelloCordova/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.camera/CDVJpegHeaderWriter.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(2 failures)
2014-01-16 14:29:28.653 xcodebuild[2059:1007] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID 37B30044-3B14-46BA-ABAA-F01000C27B63 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/XCode4_beginning_of_line.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2014-01-16 14:29:29.243 xcodebuild[2059:5c03]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-3575/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/SpecificationTypes/XCGccMakefileDependencies.m:78
Details:  Failed to load dependencies output contents from ``/Users/william/working/pluginapp/platforms/ios/build/HelloCordova.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HelloCordova.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVCamera.d''. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “CDVCamera.d” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo=0x7f93dba28370 {NSFilePath=/Users/william/working/pluginapp/platforms/ios/build/HelloCordova.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HelloCordova.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVCamera.d, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f93dba282a0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}. User info: {
    NSFilePath = "/Users/william/working/pluginapp/platforms/ios/build/HelloCordova.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HelloCordova.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVCamera.d";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. No such file or directory\"";
}.
Function: void XCGccMakefileDependenciesParsePathsFromRuleFile(NSString *__strong, F) [F = <lambda at /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-3575/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/SpecificationTypes/XCGccMakefileDependencies.m:168:73>]
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f93dba28300>{name = (null), num = 7}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2014-01-16 14:29:29.262 xcodebuild[2059:2007]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-3575/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/SpecificationTypes/XCGccMakefileDependencies.m:78
Details:  Failed to load dependencies output contents from ``/Users/william/working/pluginapp/platforms/ios/build/HelloCordova.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HelloCordova.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVJpegHeaderWriter.d''. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “CDVJpegHeaderWriter.d” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo=0x7f93dba19310 {NSFilePath=/Users/william/working/pluginapp/platforms/ios/build/HelloCordova.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HelloCordova.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVJpegHeaderWriter.d, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f93db7bed50 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}. User info: {
    NSFilePath = "/Users/william/working/pluginapp/platforms/ios/build/HelloCordova.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HelloCordova.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVJpegHeaderWriter.d";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. No such file or directory\"";
}.
Function: void XCGccMakefileDependenciesParsePathsFromRuleFile(NSString *__strong, F) [F = <lambda at /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-3575/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/SpecificationTypes/XCGccMakefileDependencies.m:168:73>]
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f93db8a9720>{name = (null), num = 8}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC build/HelloCordova.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HelloCordova.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVCamera.o HelloCordova/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.camera/CDVCamera.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC build/HelloCordova.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HelloCordova.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVJpegHeaderWriter.o HelloCordova/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.camera/CDVJpegHeaderWriter.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(2 failures)

    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/compile.js:65:22)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:5)
```

However, if I never open the project in xcode, the plugins install and "cordova build" works fine.  What could be causing this?

Comment: This command will give more verbose output, which might help: cordova -d build ios